# How do I set a wide Twitter cover photo?

Tags: twitter

How do I configure a wide Twitter cover photo like the top image on this profile: https://twitter.com/Taupoweddings

I don't see it in my Twitter settings anywhere.

Comment: That’s the new profile page design, that will be rolled out in the following weeks, so probably it’s just a matter of time till you’ll see the option.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why some profiles get it sooner than others? Several of my Twitter pages have thousands and thousands more (real, so not purchased) followers.

Comment: it's random. Doesn't depend on whether you have a thousand followers or ten

Comment: [Related](https://twitter.com/Support/status/453565075610025984).

Answer (score 1):

On Tuesday, April 8, 2014, [Twitter announced](http://blog.twitter.com/2014/coming-soon-a-whole-new-you-in-your-twitter-profile) they are rolling out a new personal profile design and that it will be "coming soon to everyone...in the coming weeks." So just hang tight and you'll soon be able to have your own version.

Additionally, here's a [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/the-design-process-behind-twitters-revamped-profiles/) about the profile update, including some other new features like pinning tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your [Twitter settings](https://twitter.com/settings/profile) and change the "Header" by uploading a new file. The recommended size is 1500 px × 500 px.

[image: Twitter settings]

You can also do it directly from your profile (assuming you're logged in).

[image: Change header from profile]

More information at the [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/127871).